# File not attached on email when sending

Tags: android

I am writing a numbers to a file and want to send the file to an email.
The file is received by emails however is empty.

But when I looked at the "data/data/com.example.write_file/files/samplefile.txt" the file is
ok and my records are written.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong please ?

```
package com.example.write_file;

+import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {  
private EditText getInput;     
    int D;
    String W;
    char chr;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.getInput);       
     D=0; 
   TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   textView1.setText("Write a number you want to send in the txt file") ; 

}

public void onClick(View view) {        

    write_file();    

    D=D+1;
    W=getInput.getText().toString();  //will get a string 
     if (getInput.getText().length() > 0){       
      chr=W.charAt(0);}  //W convert to char 
        switch (view.getId())    {
        case R.id.button1:
          if (((chr==(char)45)&&(getInput.getText().length() < 2))||(getInput.getText().length() == 0)){             
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a text",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();               
            return;
          }   

            TextView getInput1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            getInput1.setText("Write a number you want to send in the txt file") ;
          break;                 }                        

}   

public void onClick2(View view) {       
 sendfile();
 finish();  
}      

public void write_file() {  //writes into local not to a sdcard

    try { // catches IOException below            
        FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("samplefile.txt",MODE_APPEND); 
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);              
        osw.append(W + "\n");  // Write the string to the file  - "\n" similar to writeln in pascal (use wordpad not notepad)  

        osw.flush();
        osw.close();

        if (D>=55) {    finish();}

        Toast.makeText(this, "I am writing to the file",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       // the file you can find in DDMS-File Explorer-"/data/data/your_project_package_structure/files/samplefile.txt"
       // there is an icon mobile phone for pulling file from device or putting file onto device    
}
    catch (IOException ioe) 
    {Toast.makeText(this, "Exception-file not exists?",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
 }
/*    
public void sendfile(){
    String nfile;
    nfile="samplefile.txt";
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, new String[] 
            {"xxxx@yyyy.com"}); 
    emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
    "File attached.");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("data/data/com.example.write_file/files"+ nfile));
       startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,
    "Send email using.."));

    Toast.makeText(this, "The file was sent",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}   */
public void sendfile(){
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, new String[] 
            {"xxxx@yyyy.com"}); 
    emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
    "File attached.");
    File file = getFileStreamPath("samplefile.txt");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+file.getAbsolutePath()));
       startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,
    "Send email using.."));

    Toast.makeText(this, "The file was sent",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 }
}    

**in the manifest I put:**
<provider
android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
android:authorities="com.example.write_file"
android:exported="false"
android:grantUriPermissions="true">
<meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/my_path" />
</provider>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.write_file.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

**and in the  my_path.xml :**
<paths>
<files-path name="files" path="files/"/>    
</paths>
```

Answer (score 3):

First, third-party apps do not have access to your internal storage. Either write your file to external storage or [try `FileProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) to provide selective access to internal storage.

Second, **never hardcode paths**. Your code will fail on many Android devices. Use `getFilesDir()` or `getFileStreamPath()`, instead of hardcoding `data/data/com.example.write_file/files`.

Comment: I edited the code(above) but it still doesn't work. Could you please check what is wrong now? thanks

Comment: @user2556278: As I wrote, third-party apps do not have access to your internal storage. Either write your file to external storage or try `FileProvider` to provide selective access to internal storage.

Comment: @m0skit0: Oh, that's bad too, but that would not prevent the code from working.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the External Storage to send the email. If you do using application data file path which currently you are doing then you will get the Permission denied exception.

Instead of that save the file in external storage and then send it to using Intent.